# Android - Will the value of isFinishing() remain true after an Activity has been destroyed?

Tags: android, activity-lifecycle

Apologies if this question sounds incredibly basic. I have an `Activity` that has an asynchronous network callback. The callback can execute after a user leaves the Activity.

As a check I'd like to use `isFinishing()` (I cannot use `isDestroyed()` as my min API level is 16 and not 17 which `isDestroyed()` requires).

Can I use `isFinishing()` in the callback to ensure that my logic executes only when the Activity is not destroyed?

More specifically does `isFinishing()` return true for an Activity that is destroyed by calling `finish()` even after `onDestroy()` is called ?

I also had a look at the source code. Here is `isFinishing()`:

```
    public boolean isFinishing() {
        return mFinished;
    }
```

And here is finish() where the variable is set to true:

```
   /**
     * Finishes the current activity and specifies whether to remove the task associated with this
     * activity.
     */
    private void finish(boolean finishTask) {
        if (mParent == null) {
            int resultCode;
            Intent resultData;
            synchronized (this) {
                resultCode = mResultCode;
                resultData = mResultData;
            }
            if (false) Log.v(TAG, "Finishing self: token=" + mToken);
            try {
                if (resultData != null) {
                    resultData.prepareToLeaveProcess();
                }
                if (ActivityManagerNative.getDefault()
                        .finishActivity(mToken, resultCode, resultData, finishTask)) {
                    mFinished = true;
                }
            } catch (RemoteException e) {
                // Empty
            }
        } else {
            mParent.finishFromChild(this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Call this when your activity is done and should be closed.  The
     * ActivityResult is propagated back to whoever launched you via
     * onActivityResult().
     */
    public void finish() {
        finish(false);
    }
```

I also had a look at [Understanding of isFinishing()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227071/understanding-of-isfinishing)
but I can't seem to derive an answer to this particular question.

Comment: same as the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227071/understanding-of-isfinishing

Comment: I referenced that in the post, but I can't seem to derive an answer to my question. "More specifically does isFinishing() return true for an Activity that is destroyed by calling finish() even after onDestroy() is called ?"

Comment: Refer to this thread for more details about isFinishing http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227071/understanding-of-isfinishing

Answer (score 3):

Your question is probably as good an answer as any answer could be since the [javadoc](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#isFinishing()) of `Activity.isFinishing()` does not specify the return value for an already-destroyed `Activity`. However, judging by the [source](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/Activity.java) it seems that the not-at-all-confusingly-named `mFinished` (used by `isFinishing()`) is never set to `false` (other than on initialisation) and so once set to `true` will always stay that value.  Having said that, `mFinished` is package-private so in theory another class could be modifying that value. In practice, I think it is safe to assume that `isFinishing()` returns true iff an `Activity` is finishing or has finished finishing!

In other words, `isFinishing() == isFinishing() || isDestroyed()`

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm that I replaced `(isFinishing() || isDestroyed)` with `isFinishing()` and got a number of IllegalArgumentExceptions from Glide with the error `You cannot start a load for a destroyed activity`.  Not perfect evidence, but enough to convince me that, at least on some platforms / devices, the two are not the same.