# Gradle dependency to be added for vitamio player 5 in android studio

Tags: android, vitamio

I am  using vitamio player 5 in my project i have upgraded from version 4.2.2 due to The vulnerabilities issue in Vitamio lower version player, but now i don't know what gradle dependency to be added to my app.  I have added the latest version of player but don't know what dependency to be added please somebody help me

Comment: did you try this dependency, dependencies {
    compile 'com.charonchui.vitamio:vitamio:4.2.2'
}
...?

Comment: 4.2.2 is showing vulnerabilities issue while uploading in playstore

Comment: no ans for my ques????

Comment: Refer to this link to know more about isFinishing() <http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227071/understanding-of-isfinishing>``

Comment: What you mean  by "Latest version of player"?