# location manager updating after removing updates

Tags: android, android-location

I have a problem with my location manager updates. Every time I quit an activity or when I quit the whole app location manager keeps updating location.

I wanted the app to keep updating location when the display is turned off so I used

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
    super.onPause();
    if (this.isFinishing()) {
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
         }
}
```

I've put `locationManager.removeUpdates(this);` even in `onBackPressed()` method bud after quitting the activity by pressing back or quitting the app the manager is stil requesting updates.

Answer (score 0):

Refer [Understanding of isFinishing()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5227071/understanding-of-isfinishing)
When the user switches to another app, your application is not necessarily killed by the OS until it needs to free up the resources. Hence, isFinishing() may retrun `true` while onPause() is being called.
Later, when the OS does kill your app, the onPause() is not called as the app is already in background.
Use the `onStop()` call.

Comment: Sadly this didn't work. Somehow when I press back button to go back to main activity the location manager keeps updating location (location icon blinking in notification bar) I've tried to put everywhere locationManager.removeUpdates(this); but it just does not stop updating my location.

Answer (score 0):

just set "location manager" and "Location updater listener" to NULL :

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
super.onPause();
if (this.isFinishing()) {
    locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
     locationManager=null;
     }
}
```